# jQuery ticker works in jsfiddle, but it doesn't work in .HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this jQuery newsticker that works in jsFiddle, but if I transfer it to an HTML file, it doesn't work any more. Everything is exactly the same, but it doesn't work which is weird.

Here's the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RXH6w/9/

```
$.noConflict();
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
    function NewsTickerAutoPlay() {
        $(".NewsTicker li:first-child").slideUp(function () {
            $(this).appendTo(".NewsTicker").fadeIn();
        });
    }
    setInterval(function () {
        NewsTickerAutoPlay()
    }, 1000);
});
```

And here's the HTML that I copied from my jsFiddle: http://jehzlau.net/ticker.html

Everything is copied exactly the same, but it doesn't work in my HTML. I hope someone here can trace my simple problem.

Comment: Thanks everyone. It's now work. I just forgot to include window.onload=function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your HTML with the code below. Remember by adding "/show" at the end of the JSFiddle URL will lead you the whole page everything in it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Simple NewsTicker - jsFiddle demo</title>

  <script type='text/javascript' src='/js/lib/dummy.js'></script>




  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">


      <script type='text/javascript' src="http:///ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


  <style type='text/css'>
    .NewsTicker {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    line-height:20px;
    height:20px;
    overflow:hidden
}
  </style>



<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
window.onload=function(){
$.noConflict();
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {

function NewsTickerAutoPlay() {
    $(".NewsTicker li:first-child").slideUp(function () {
        $(this).appendTo(".NewsTicker").fadeIn();
    });
}

setInterval(function () {
    NewsTickerAutoPlay()
}, 1000);

});
}//]]>  

</script>


</head>
<body>
  <ul class="NewsTicker">
<li>Etisalat and Huawei Conduct First 400G Trial Optical Transport Network in Middle East and North Africa</li>
<li>Huawei to Deploy Africa's First Smart eLTE Urban Railway Communications System in Ethiopia</li>
</ul>

</body>


</html>
```

Comment: whoa! that worked! Thanks! Hahahaha.. I'm sooo dummbbbb.. >_<

Comment: Saw it, it's just the window.onload=function that I forgot to include. Thanks again for the help Berdiya. :D

Answer (score -1):

You are missing an *a* at "text/javascript".

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it's the window.onload=function. I forgot to include it. Haha! :D

Comment: You shouldn't need window.onload, but you need the *a* that is missing in your script tag ;) But well it's running so nevermind.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. :D Yeah I tried to remove the onload and it still works. Hahaha! :D You're right that the text/javascript is missing. :D

Comment: Thanks also for the sample. I never thought this can work without the onload. Thanks again. I wish I could up vote you but I don't have enough rep. :(